# Can't use Direct Query mode in tabular project In Analysis service

Tags: ssas, .net-framework-version, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I am using sql server data tools to create the tabular project. I want to create the model in Direct Query mode.
 I am using Azure Analysis Services (the one where we connect via asazure://...). I changed the query mode of model to direct query and when i am trying to connect to azure data warehouse as a source for pulling the data.
It gives me following error:

```
We’re sorry – This data provider can only be used if Microsoft .NET Full Framework 4.0 or higher is installed. You can download the Microsoft .NET Full Framework 4.0 here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243132
```

I have the latest version of .NET framework installed on my machine.
But it works fine when I use the same model in InMemory Mode. 
Is this the limitation of Azure Analysis server? Is Azure analysis server does not support Direct Query Mode?
Please help me out.